# Adding additional fields (with validation) to Devise view/model in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

It seems there's not a whole lot of documentation out there covering how to add custom fields to a Devise authentication solution in a Rails 3 app.

Along with the required e-mail and password for users to sign up, I'd like a few other custom fields put in and validated and since there are no controllers generated with Devise, how does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `rails generate devise_views` all the views for the features you selected will go in your app/views/devise folder. You could simply add the fields defined in your model to those views.  If you need to customize the controller, create

```
class YourModel::DeviseFeaturesController
```

by DeviseFeatures I meant RegistrationsController, ConfirmationsController or whichever features you decided to use.

There is a great screencast about it: [RailsCasts-customizing-devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise)

Comment: Can you provide an example for us newbies out there? The RailsCasts doesn't dwell into this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I needed this same thing.  There is a great article I found to help me:

http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/rails-%E2%80%93-add-custom-fields-to-devise-user-model/